# Crispy forms works in local site but not in production site

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

login.html:

```
<div class = "container">
    <h2 class = "text-center">Login</h2>

    <form method = 'post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }} <!--'form' comes from login view imported in urls-->
        <div class = "text-center">
            <br/>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type = 'submit'>Login</button>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

In settings.py I added it to installed apps and specified the crispy template pack:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
```

and this works well when ran locally, but when I try to run `python3.6 manage.py migrate` in an ssh connection to my server I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/obrien98/webapps/core/lib/python3.6/Django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/obrien98/webapps/core/lib/python3.6/Django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/obrien98/webapps/core/lib/python3.6/Django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/obrien98/webapps/core/lib/python3.6/Django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/obrien98/webapps/core/lib/python3.6/Django-1.11.5-py3.6.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'
```

Comment: did you install `crispy_forms` on your server? show `pip3 freeze` on server, please.

Comment: that command returned:
'psycopg2==2.5.4', does this mean i have to do pip install django-crispy-forms in this same directory?